# Conexão em Bases de Dados separadas PDO - (multi-tenancy )

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, conexão, multi-tenancy

Tenho o seguinte senário para a minha aplicação:
Tenho uma aplicação PHP + MySql, com conexão em PDO, preciso que a aplicação seja compartilhada com todas as empresas cadastradas, porém cada empresa terá sua base de dados separadamente.

**ESTRUTURA DA APLICAÇÃO**

***Conexão:***

**1** - Con.class.php => Responsável pela conexão com o banco usando PDO - SingleTon

**2** - Config.php => Através de define(); recebe os valores a serem passados para conexão - (Host, User, DB...)

***Banco de Dados Central:***

**3** - TABELA Empresas => Recebe as empresas que vão usar a aplicação, contendo as informações de conexão - (Host, User, DB, Senha)

***Bancos de Dados do Clientes (db1, bd2, db3.....):***

**4** - TABELA Usuários => Contém as informações dos usuários, inclusive o "ID_EMPRESA" para referenciar a qual empresa o mesmo pertence além das informações de login- (user_login, user_senha, user_email...)

> Como eu posso fazer para que cada empresa log na sua base que será
>   criada ao cadastrar as empresas, além de não ter o conhecimento
>   avançado no PHP, não encontrei uma ajuda sobre isso pesquisando.

**CÓDIGOS**

***Con.class.php***

```
<?php
class Conn {

    private static $Host = SIS_DB_HOST;
    private static $User = SIS_DB_USER;
    private static $Pass = SIS_DB_PASS;
    private static $Dbsa = SIS_DB_DBSA;

    private static $Connect = null;

    private static function Conectar() {
        try {
            if (self::$Connect == null):
                $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . self::$Host . ';dbname=' . self::$Dbsa;
                $options = [ PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES UTF8'];
                self::$Connect = new PDO($dsn, self::$User, self::$Pass, $options);
                self::$Connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            endif;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            PHPErro($e->getCode(), $e->getMessage(), $e->getFile(), $e->getLine());
            die;
        }

        return self::$Connect;
    }

    public static function getConn() {
        return self::Conectar();
    }

    private function __construct() {

    }

    private function __clone() {

    }

    private function __wakeup() {

    }

}
```

***Config.php***

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == $urlcentral):
    define('HOST', $linkBanco);
    define('USER', $userBanco);
    define('PASS', $senhaBanco);
    define('DBSA', $nomeBanco);
else:
    define('HOST_CLIENTE', $linkBancoCliente);
    define('USER_CLIENTE', $userBancoCliente);
    define('PASS_CLIENTE', $senhaBancoCliente);
    define('DBSA_CLIENTE', $nomeBancoCliente);
endif;
```

Será que é possível realizar estão ação? Quando o usuário entrar com o
Login e Senha, verificar a qual empresa ele pertence, e levar as
informações de conexão do banco de dados e ele ser conectado na base
da empresa a qual ele pertence. Obrigado!

Comment: Eu acho que o maior problema aí está na estruturação da classe. Não faz sentido alterar a constante para alterar o valor da propriedade das classes. Por quê não instanciar a classe com os valores passado por parâmetros, de acordo com o cliente?

Comment: Jovem, se tiver alguma outra dúvida, não exite em usar os comentários para perguntar...

Answer (score 2):

No seu caso, meu jovem, eu reimplementaria essa conexão. Creio que Singleton nesse caso (e na maioria, na minha humilde opinião) engessa mais uma estrutura do que ajuda.

Eu acredito que uma boa opção seria você ter uma lista de conexões salvas em um `array`, separadas cada uma por um índice, para indicar a aplicação que cada uma pertence.

Em seguida, você pode usar o padrão Multiton combinado com Factory, para poder gerar essas conexões únicas...

Eu fiz um esboço apenas pra exemplificar, mas você pode criar baseando-se numa estrutura similiar a essa:

```
class Connection

{
    protected $dsn;

    protected $user;

    protected $password;

    protected $options;

    public function __construct(array $options)
    {
        // monta as variáveis de acordo com o option

        //$this->dsn = $this->buildDsn($options); 

        // ...
    }

    public function getPdo()
    {
        if ($this->pdo === null)
        {
            $this->pdo = new \PDO($this->dsn, $this->user, $this->password, $this->options);
        }

        return $this->pdo;
    }
}

class ConnectionFactory
{
    protected static $connections = [
        'app_1' => [
            'host' => '...',
            'password' => '...',
        ],

        'app_2' => [
            'host' => '...',
            'password' => '...'
        ]
    ];

    protected static $instances = [];

    // implementação multiton

    public static function getConnection($name)
    {
        if (! isset(static::$instances[$name])) {

            static::$instances[$name] = new Connection(static::$connections[$name]);
        }

        return static::$instances[$name];
    }
}
```

Observe agora, que você poderia criar as instância de conexão com o banco de dados, normalmente, de acordo com o cliente desejado.

Exemplo:

```
  $db1 = ConnectionFactory::getConnection('app_1');

  $db2 = ConnectionFactory::getConnection('app_2');
```

No caso acima, as chamadas poderiam ocorrer em qualquer lugar da aplicação, pois as construções das instâncias são armazenadas em um `array` e, caso exista, não são recriadas, apenas reaproveitadas.

No caso acima, eu combinei Factory com Multiton (um Singleton baseado nos parâmetros) para poder manter a estrutura similar ao que você tem atualmente (você deve ter um motivo pra estar usando singleton).

Comment: Amigo usei Singleton no projeto porque no início não tinha essa necessidade de hoje, então pensei que ao invés de fazer tudo do zero, seria possível alterar somente a parte de conexão, já que todo o projeto está pronto para uso. Vou tentar aplicar o que me ensinou acima. Te agradeço muito.